# Set timer in asp.net page

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

How can I set a timer on my asp.net page so that it will pause/wait for few seconds (say 5 seconds) then do rest of stuff in the code?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Add delay on client side (in browser) or on server side?

Comment: Why would you let your user have to wait for 5 seconds? ASP.NET simply needs to do the calculations + rendering on the server, spitting it out as html to the browser. Ajax was introduced to provide users with a faster system of displaying data. This is quite opposite of what endusers want.

Comment: I hope this is for some proof-of-concept and not real-work application. If you are releasing this into the wild, let me know what site so I can avoid it!

Comment: Like @Korin said, we need to know what exactly you're trying to accomplish because it can be done either server side or client side.  It would be helpful to know WHY you need to wait to figure out what the most appropriate solution is.

Comment: Ignore the doubters @Tony. Users are bastards. Stick it to 'em.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pause execution on the server for some reason, you could simply invoke the Sleep method on the current thread, like so...

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
```

If you want to pause execution in the browser, you could try [the trick documented here](http://www.sean.co.uk/a/webdesign/javascriptdelay.shtm).

Unfortunately, as a commenter mentioned, that javascript trick will block the browser process. Firefox offers an alternative that doesn't block execution [documented here](http://www.balistupa.com/blog/2010/07/sleep-or-wait-process-on-javascript-thread/), but unfortunately that's only Firefox.

Comment: re: The link to the trick, be VERY careful doing a closed loop for any length of time - this doesn't stop JS for that duration, it makes it loop rapidly - probably using up 100% CPU and potentially triggering the "A script on this page is taking a long time to execute - Do you want to stop it?"  dialogue. It's not a technique you should use in a production environment

Comment: @Basiclife - that's for your input. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could do `Thread.Sleep(millisecondsToWait)` but this might cause a bad user experience.